# Multiple dlls compiled from single C# project not compiling in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have a single project that is compiling multiple classes into separate .dlls in separate directories at build time. Each class has its own Assembly information defined outside the namespace for the class, e.g.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("SomeDescription")]
```

This is so that after the solution has been built, I can create .nuspec files based on each of the .dlls and then create .nupkg files based off those .nuspec files.

This all works perfectly using VS2013, however our build machine uses VS2015 which complains that there is duplicate AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion etc etc. defined and the build fails.

Is there a way of allowing this setup to be built in VS2015 that I'm missing? For reference this is the MSBuild Targets I have setup to perform the .dll creation:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BuiltDll Include="Thing\Foo\Bar.cs" />
  <BuiltDll Include="Thing1\Hello\There.cs" />
  <BuiltDll Include="Thing2\How\Ironic.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CreateDirectories">
   <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)%(BuiltDll.Filename)"></MakeDir>
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildDllsRelease">
  <GetReferenceAssemblyPaths BypassFrameworkInstallChecks="False" 
     TargetFrameworkMoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
  <Output TaskParameter="FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths" 
    PropertyName="path" />
  </GetReferenceAssemblyPaths>
<CSC Sources="@(BuiltDll)" TargetType="library" 
  References="@(PluginReference)" 
  Resources="@(ManifestResourceWithNoCulture);
  @(ManifestNonResxWithNoCultureOnDisk);
  @(CompiledLicenseFile);" 
  OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)%(BuiltDll.Filename)\%
  (BuiltDll.FileName).dll" EmitDebugInformation="false" />
</Target>

<Target Name="BuildDllsDebug">
  <GetReferenceAssemblyPaths BypassFrameworkInstallChecks="False" 
    TargetFrameworkMoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
  <Output TaskParameter="FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths" 
    PropertyName="path" />
  </GetReferenceAssemblyPaths>
  <CSC Sources="@(BuiltDll)" TargetType="library" 
    References="@(PluginReference)" 
    Resources="@(ManifestResourceWithNoCulture);
    @(ManifestNonResxWithNoCultureOnDisk);@(CompiledLicenseFile);" 
    OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)%(BuiltDll.FileName).dll" 
    EmitDebugInformation="false" />
 </Target>
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <CallTarget Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" 
     Targets="BuildDllsDebug">
   </CallTarget>
   <CallTarget Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" 
     Targets="CreateDirectories;BuildDllsRelease">
   </CallTarget>
</Target>
```

The only other alternatives I can think is to have a separate project for each file I want a dll for (but this will mean upwards of 20 new projects) or creating the nuspec file manually and having it in the solution rather than after the build.

Comment: Can't reproduce, and the code you show looks fine. The duplicate attribute error can only occur if more than one of your source files containing attributes is passed to CSC at once. Which could for example occur if your project's Compile ItemGroup includes them. If you have the project in version control, check if there are any differences from upgrading, maybe somehow the files are now all included in the build?

Comment: Figure out what the problem was. There was unit tests running on the build machine that had the classes with assembly information set as linked files. Turns out we had to do this in order to get the assemblies linked correctly for unit testing. After a bit of re-work, I've abandoned the idea of having the assembly information in the class in favour of a nuspec file in the solution for each class. But your idea of checking the upgrade log led me to the build log on the server which identified that it was the unit test project that had the problem.

Comment: @tachikaze_, Glad to know you resolved this issue, you can convert your comment to answer and mark it, so that it is benefit to other communities has the same issue.